Same select queries returns different result
I get strange results when I try to perform operations on the tmpAzioni table. Before the INSERT where the UDF is executed, everything is correct, but from that point onward, only the queries SELECT * FROM tmpAzioni give correct results.
This is the table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblAzioni (
        ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Listino VARCHAR(100),
        Sequenza INT,
        Prezzo DECIMAL(19, 8),
        AzionePrezzo VARCHAR(50),
        Sconto1 DECIMAL(13, 4),
        AzioneSconto1 VARCHAR(50),
        Sconto2 DECIMAL(13, 4),
        AzioneSconto2 VARCHAR(50),
        Sconto3 DECIMAL(13, 4),
        AzioneSconto3 VARCHAR(50),
        Sconto4 DECIMAL(13, 4),
        AzioneSconto4 VARCHAR(50),
        Sconto5 DECIMAL(13, 4),
        AzioneSconto5 VARCHAR(50),
        SeScontoTarget INT,
        TipoScontoTarget CHAR(3),
        ScontoTarget DECIMAL(13, 4),
        AzioneScontoTarget VARCHAR(50),
        Note VARCHAR(1000)
    );

From this point onward everything get strange:
INSERT INTO tblAzioni (ID, Listino, Sequenza, Prezzo,  AzionePrezzo, Sconto1, AzioneSconto1, Sconto2, AzioneSconto2, Sconto3, AzioneSconto3, Sconto4, AzioneSconto4, Sconto5, AzioneSconto5, SeScontoTarget, TipoScontoTarget, ScontoTarget, AzioneScontoTarget)
    SELECT *
    FROM JSON_TABLE(
        udfCalcolaCondizioni(JsonTabAzioni, CodArticolo, Quantita, Data),
        '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            ID INT PATH '$.ID',
                    Listino VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.Listino',
                    Sequenza INT PATH '$.Sequenza',
                    Prezzo DECIMAL(19,8) PATH '$.Prezzo',
                    AzionePrezzo VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.AzionePrezzo',
                    Sconto1 DECIMAL(13,4) PATH '$.Sconto1',
                    AzioneSconto1 VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.AzioneSconto1',
                    Sconto2 DECIMAL(13,4) PATH '$.Sconto2',
                    AzioneSconto2 VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.AzioneSconto2',
                    Sconto3 DECIMAL(13,4) PATH '$.Sconto3',
                    AzioneSconto3 VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.AzioneSconto3',
                    Sconto4 DECIMAL(13,4) PATH '$.Sconto4',
                    AzioneSconto4 VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.AzioneSconto4',
                    Sconto5 DECIMAL(13,4) PATH '$.Sconto5',
                    AzioneSconto5 VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.AzioneSconto5',
                    SeScontoTarget INT PATH '$.SeScontoTarget',
                    TipoScontoTarget CHAR(3) PATH '$.TipoScontoTarget',
                    ScontoTarget DECIMAL(13,4) PATH '$.ScontoTarget',
                    AzioneScontoTarget VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.AzioneScontoTarget'
        )
    ) AS JsonAzioni;

If I specify the fields instead of using the *, the results are incorrect here as well.
The strangest thing is that if I execute a query like
SELECT * FROM tblAzioni;

I get these results.
1   LID00001    5   128.30000000    Somma   0.0000  Somma   0.0000  Somma   0.0000  Somma   0.0000  Somma   0.0000  Somma   1   PRZ 60.9600 Somma   

However, if I execute this query:
SELECT ID, Listino, Sequenza, Prezzo, AzionePrezzo, Sconto1, AzioneSconto1, Sconto2, AzioneSconto2, Sconto3, AzioneSconto3, Sconto4, AzioneSconto4, Sconto5, AzioneSconto5, SeScontoTarget, TipoScontoTarget, ScontoTarget, AzioneScontoTarget 
FROM tblAzioni;

some fields return different results.
1   LID00001    5   128.30000000    Somma   0.0000  Somma   0.0000  Somma   0.0000  Somma   0.0000  Somma   0.0000  Somma   1       0.0000  Somma

So after this point i can't rely on my result cause everything is broken

probably a datatype issue

The second query is missing the Note column in the SELECT list. That will be included in the SELECT * query.

The difference in results is PRZ 60.9600. Where is that supposed to come from?

It may help if you could include the column headers in the two "results" that you have added to the question. Since we aren't familiar with your data we are left guessing what values belong to which columns based on column ordinal and guess work. Something definitely feels off, but I can't imagine any mysql feature set that would cause a regular table like tblAzioni to surface two different values for the same record merely because of "select splat" versus listing columns.

Using JSON seems unnecessary; do without it.
